# C# Sum between Rows in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to sum not specific rows of a datatable based on a string which is on specific column. For example, String Test was found on row0 row1, add subtotal row below, String Test1 was found only on row2, add subtotal row below etc. Of course there must be a footer row with sum of subtotals:
Before:

```
Col0 | Col1  | Col2 | Col3
xxxx | Test  | 12   | 21 
yyyy | Test  | 13   | 22
zzzz | Test1 | 14   | 23 
aaaa | Test2 | 15   | 24
bbbb | Test2 | 16   | 25
```

What i want:

```
Col0 | Col1   | Col2 | Col3 ...Col6
xxxx | Test   | 12   | 21 
yyyy | Test   | 13   | 22
     |SubTotal| 25   | 43
zzzz | Test1  | 14   | 23
     |SubTotal| 14   | 23
aaaa | Test2  | 15   | 24
bbbb | Test2  | 16   | 25
     |SubTotal| 31   | 49
     | Total  | 70   | 115
```

What i have done so far.

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col0", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(decimal));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(decimal));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col4", typeof(decimal));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col5", typeof(decimal));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Col6", typeof(decimal));

    DataTable dTable_1 = new DataTable();


    string Sql_Conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ora_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Sql_Conn))
        {
            using (OracleCommand Sql_Cmd = new OracleCommand(""))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter dt = new OracleDataAdapter(Sql_Cmd))
                {
                    Sql_Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 ,Col0, Col1, " +
                                           " SUM(TEST04) Col2,  " +
                                           " SUM(TEST03) Col3,  " +
                                           " SUM(TEST03)+SUM(TEST04) Col4,  " +
                                           " SUM(TEST05) Col5,  " +
                                           " SUM(TEST03)+SUM(TEST04)+SUM(TEST05) Col6  " +
                                           " FROM TEST  " +
                                           " WHERE A=:A  " +
                                           " GROUP BY Col0,Col1" +
                                           " ORDER BY Col0,Col1";
                    Sql_Cmd.Connection = con;

                    Sql_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    Sql_Cmd.BindByName = true;
                    Sql_Cmd.Parameters.Add(":A", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = A;
                    con.Open();
                    using (OracleDataReader Rdr = Sql_Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        decimal Total_Col2 = 0;
                        decimal Total_Col3 = 0;
                        decimal Total_Col4 = 0;
                        decimal Total_Col5 = 0;
                        decimal Total_Col6 = 0;

                        int ii = 0;
                        while (Rdr.Read())
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dTable.NewRow();
                            dr["Col0"] = Rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : Rdr.GetString(1);
                            dr["Col1"] = Rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : Rdr.GetString(2);
                            dr["Col2"] = Rdr.GetDecimal(3);
                            dr["Col3"] = Rdr.GetDecimal(4);
                            dr["Col4"] = Rdr.GetDecimal(5);
                            dr["Col5"] = Rdr.GetDecimal(6);
                            dr["Col6"] = Rdr.GetDecimal(7);                               

                            if (dTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                Total_Col2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Col2"]);
                                Total_Col3 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Col3"]);
                                Total_Col4 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Col4"]);
                                Total_Col5 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Col5"]);
                                Total_Col6 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Col6"]);
                            }
                            else if (dTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                int current = dTable.Rows.Count;
                                int previous = dTable.Rows.Count - 1;
                                if (dr["Col1"].ToString() == dTable.Rows[previous]["Col1"].ToString())
                                {
                                    Total_Col2 = Total_Col2 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col2"]);
                                    Total_Col3 = Total_Col3 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col3"]);
                                    Total_Col4 = Total_Col4 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col4"]);
                                    Total_Col5 = Total_Col5 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col5"]);
                                    Total_Col6 = Total_Col6 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col6"]);
                                    ii = ii + 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                        if (dTable.Rows.Count != 1)
                                        {
                                            DataRow Dr_New = dTable.NewRow();
                                            Dr_New["Col0"] = "";
                                            Dr_New["Col1"] = "Subtotal";
                                            Dr_New["Col2"] = Total_Col2 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col2"]); 
                                            Dr_New["Col3"] = Total_Col3 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col3"]); 
                                            Dr_New["Col4"] = Total_Col4 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col4"]);
                                            Dr_New["Col5"] = Total_Col5 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col5"]);
                                            Dr_New["Col6"] = Total_Col6 + Convert.ToDecimal(dTable.Rows[previous]["Col6"]);
                                            dTable.Rows.Add(Dr_New);
                                            dTable.Rows.Add();
                                            Total_Col2 = 0;
                                            Total_Col3 = 0;
                                            Total_Col4 = 0;
                                            Total_Col5 = 0;
                                            Total_Col6 = 0;
                                            ii = 0;
                                        }
                                        else if (dTable.Rows.Count == 1)
                                        {
                                            DataRow Dr_New = dTable.NewRow();
                                            Dr_New["Col0"] = "-";
                                            Dr_New["Col1"] = "Subtotal";
                                            Dr_New["Col2"] = Total_Col2;
                                            Dr_New["Col3"] = Total_Col3;
                                            Dr_New["Col4"] = Total_Col4;
                                            Dr_New["Col5"] = Total_Col5;
                                            Dr_New["Col6"] = Total_Col6;
                                            dTable.Rows.Add(Dr_New);
                                            dTable.Rows.Add();
                                            Total_Col2 = 0;
                                            Total_Col3 = 0;
                                            Total_Col4 = 0;
                                            Total_Col5 = 0;
                                            Total_Col6 = 0;
                                            ii = 0;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            dTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }

                        GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

                        decimal total_Col2 = dTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Col2") ?? 0);
                        decimal total_Col3 = dTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Col3") ?? 0);
                        decimal total_Col4 = dTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Col4") ?? 0);
                        decimal total_Col5 = dTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Col5") ?? 0);
                        decimal total_Col6 = dTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Col6") ?? 0);

                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = "Total";
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = total_Col2.ToString("N2");
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = total_Col3.ToString("N2");
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = total_Col4.ToString("N2");
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[5].Text = total_Col5.ToString("N2");
                        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[6].Text = total_Col6.ToString("N2");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Above code not working as i want and i think that is very complicate.
Any help appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ROLLUP clause, see https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-rollup/
You want something like:

```
SELECT 
    c1, c2, aggregate_function(c3)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY ROLLUP (c1, c2);
```